# orderBy query not working so trying to distinct manual but cant get it work

Tags: reactjs, react-native, foreach, google-cloud-firestore

I want to make an array of list of unique cities that appear in my query.
so I did like:

```js
this.dbRef
  .where("Destination", "==", this.state.delegation)
  .orderBy("Location", "desc")
  .get() // .where('Gender', '==', 'male')
  .then((querySnapshot) => {
    /* .. */
  });
```

But it won't work with `orderBy`.. any other query working - I googled it and can't find the right answer.

So I'm trying to recover it by making the name of the cities distinct/unique

This is my code:

```js
const cityArr = [];
this.dbRef
  .where("Destination", "==", this.state.delegation)
  .get()
  .then((querySnapshot) => {
    querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
      cityArr.push({
        City: doc.data().Location,
      });
      console.log("City array:! ", cityArr); // <~~~~ working
    });
  });
```

But now I need to make it distincted.

I can see many answers like that for react but can't make it on my elements.. all the examples with arrays such as ['1,2,3,3,3,4,5,5...'] .. etc.

Anyone can help me make a working copy of the array that sets the unique names of cities?
or if you know why the `orderby` is not working? cuz then it would be easier to make simple if-loops

**Edit:**

So here what i did:

```js
this.dbRef
  .where("Destination", "==", this.state.delegation)
  //  .orderBy('Location','desc')
  .get()
  .then((querySnapshot) => {
    querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
      console.log("TESTING@#@$");
      for (let i = 0; i < cityArr.length; i++) {
        console.log(
          "DOC.DATA.LOCATION = ",
          doc.data().Location,
          "cityArr[i].city = ",
          cityArr[i].city
        );
        if (doc.data().Location == cityArr[i].city) {
          flag = 1;
          break;
        }
      }
      if (flag == 0)
        cityArr.push({
          City: doc.data().Location,
        });
      else flag = 0;
      console.log("CITY ARRAY:! ", cityArr);
      i++;
    });
  });
```

But `cityArr[i].city` is undefined.. :(

Comment: any idea? I also tried to call it on comp did mount

Comment: to get unique city values, use set instead of array.

Comment: the problem was that forEach function from query took time to finish, then the array was empty when I tried to make some unique functions. so I made simple if to fix it. that rendering stuff is really annoying, is there any method to force a refresh?